# Deserializing the InputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat@45312be2) failed

Tags: apache-flink

I start a flink master with standalone mode, and submit a jar file to read data from mysql and filter data.
But the program encountered an error : Deserializing the InputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat@45312be2) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat

Specific information as follow.

When I execute the program in IDEA, it can execute successfully. 
I've searched a lot, but can't find the answer.
Hope someone can answer my doubts.Thanks~

```
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at /10.12.65.5:6123
Using address 10.12.65.5:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://10.12.65.5:8081
Starting execution of program
Submitting job with JobID: 5336205c4de156b38ab34afa4e6c5a17. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@10.12.65.5:6123/user/jobmanager#-2083257516] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:545)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:381)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:838)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Cannot initialize task 'CHAIN DataSource (at createInput(ExecutionEnvironment.java:553) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (where: (=(abnor_flag, 0)), select: (abnor_flag))': Deserializing the InputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat@45312be2) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:478)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:429)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:926)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
    at com.sankuai.waimai.flink.FlinkJDBC$.main(FlinkJDBC.scala:51)
    at com.sankuai.waimai.flink.FlinkJDBC.main(FlinkJDBC.scala)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'CHAIN DataSource (at createInput(ExecutionEnvironment.java:553) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat)) -> FlatMap (where: (=(abnor_flag, 0)), select: (abnor_flag))': Deserializing the InputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat@45312be2) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1315)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:495)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:38)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:125)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Deserializing the InputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat@45312be2) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.InputFormatVertex.initializeOnMaster(InputFormatVertex.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:150)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.InputFormatVertex.initializeOnMaster(InputFormatVertex.java:63)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:64)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:288)
    ... 22 more`enter code here`
```

Comment: You have to include the flink-jdbc jar in the jar you pass to flink or place it in the /lib folder of the flink distribution.

Comment: I changed the jar with an allinone jar and the problem solved, thank you~